# Jackson custom serializer and deserializer with conditions

Tags: java, object, serialization, deserialization, customization

I am unable to find the correct way to manipulate the casing of a value via a custom annotation that I can control conditionally.

I have already looked into Jackson tutorials online with JsonFilters, Serialization, Deserialization - I have had most of them working but not with my desired outcome.

Custom Serializer:

```java
public class CaseSerializer extends JsonSerializer<String> {
    private boolean myCheck;

    public CaseSerializer() {
        // default
    }

    public CaseSerializer(boolean myControl) {
        this.myCheck = myControl;
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException {
        if (value != null) {
            if (myCheck) {
                generator.writeString(value.toUpperCase());
            } else {
                generator.writeString(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Person Model:

```java
public class Person {
    @JsonSerialize(using = CaseSerializer.class)
    private String title;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    public Person(String title, String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.title = title;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // getters, setters & toString
}
```

Usage:

```java
        Person person = new Person("dr", "john", "doe");

        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addSerializer(String.class,new CaseSerializer(true));

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.registerModule(module);
        String titleShouldBeUpper = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);

        System.out.println(titleShouldBeUpper);
```

From running the code provided I expect that the title field within the Person class to be uppercased and the other values to remain as they were.

(CaseSerializer(true) meaning I want to uppercase the values)

This is not the case as the code prints the following output:

```
{"title":"dr","firstName":"JOHN","lastName":"DOE"}
```

When I run the code with the CaseSerializer() without the boolean myControl set to true, the expected output is that none of the fields are uppercased.

Which is what is happening:

```
{"title":"dr","firstName":"john","lastName":"doe"}
```

This means by default nothing will change.

If I call the mapper with a true for case serialization I only want the fields where the JsonSerialize(using = CaseSerializer.class) is present.

Any ideas?

Comment: you have added the module globally to `ObjectMapper` - `module.addSerializer(String.class,new CaseSerializer(true));` so this will apply to every `String` mapping.

Comment: One solution would be to have 2 deserializers, one for uppercase and one for lowercase and annotate String fields with proper annotation.

Comment: Okay that makes sense. Any ideas on why it is skipping the only value annotated in my person class?

Comment: When using `@JsonSerialize` on your field you override settings for the module that you registered. And when it instantiates the class it uses default constructor so the boolean flag defaults to `false`

Comment: Thanks, I'll run a new test to see if i can get it to function the way I expect based on your comments.